# Google Analytics missing ~5% of sessions from iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have an ecommerce application for iOS that is reporting transactions to Google Analytics. When I compare the analytics each week with the data from the sales system, Google Analytics is always missing ~5% of the transactions.

Further investigation turned up that it's not just the transaction data that occasionally goes missing, but all data (events, screen views, etc.).

For example, I have a user that I know used the app every day last week. However, Google Analytics shows activity for every day except Tuesday. It seems like the iOS SDK occasionally stops reporting data for chunks of time, but I'm not sure why.

We're not crossing any rate limits (best I can tell) and the app isn't uninstalled from the user's device so the data shouldn't be getting deleted.

The view I'm using in Google Analytics *is* filtered and has User-ID reports enabled. (I just created a new view this week with no filters and User-ID reports disabled to see if the results are different.)

Does anyone have any thoughts about what might be causing the data to go missing?